# How do I add a comment explaining my rollback?

Tags: support, feature-request, comments, rollbacks

I don't usually roll back edits to my posts, but I have had occasion to a few times recently. When I do, the comment just says something like

> Rollback to Revision 4

For the cases in which it may not be immediately clear to the editor (or others), I'd like to explain why I'm rolling it back. I don't see any way to do that, though, without making a whole new edit.

I would like to say something like this:

> Rollback to Revision 4 - (Revision 5 incorrectly summarized the links that followed it.)

Is that possible? If not, could it be added?

Comment: [I don't usually roll back edits to my posts, but when I do, I always leave a comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5mOf.jpg).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of clicking "rollback" on the revision you want to rollback to, click "edit" on the revision you want to rollback to (which brings up the edit page with the content of that revision, rather than the current content of the post), and then don't change anything other than the revision comment.  Note that your revision comment will be preceded with "Rollback to revision X" so you don't need to type that.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41954) is quite helpful, I think.